# tab bar controller (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i'm making an application of tab bars...having 5 tabbars.i.e. home,ask,tip,inbox,disclaimer..now the problem is that i want the control to directly shift to disclaimer tab after the launch of application ..right now control shifts to home tab..which is the 1st tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:(int)];
```

The numbering of tabs starts at 0. This will take you straight to the tab that you want.

The other way of handling this would be to have a modal view that displays the disclaimer on top of everything at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Tab bar controller has a property called `selectedViewController`, set it's value to your disclaimer view controller instance like this:

```
myGlobalTabBarController.selectedViewController = myDisclaimerViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a tab bar that when selected the last tab, it displayed a new array of tab bar items, but when I went back to the first view (with the first array of tab bar items) the selection was the same index of the second array of items. This WORKED inside of this:

```
if (![myTabBarIBOutlet.selectedItem isEqual:my1stTabBarView/NavController.tabBarItem])
```

thanks for the tip!